# Spring + Spring security + Jquery: Facebook like button (like)

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, spring, spring-security

I need to create something similar to the facebook-like button with Spring 3 + Jquery.
When the user click on 'mylike' based on some conditions returned from server the button change is status. This button is displayed in every "anonymous" page (so no login is required) but when you click on this button you need to be logged in. So if an anonymous user click on it he/she should be redirected on the login page via Spring-Security.

In the Spring-Security conf I have:

// /mypage/*/* for the method GET is anonymous

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mypage")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{data1}/{data2}", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
    public String handleView {
    // returns view
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{data1}/{data2}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String handleRequest(ModelMap model, @PathVariable String      data1, @PathVariable String data2) {
    //do something for message variable
    return message;
    }
 }
```

on the JQuery side:

```
<li>
<div id="mylikecontainer">
<a id="like" href="">I like it</a>
</div>
```

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#like").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax ( {
            type: 'POST',
            url: "",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#mylikecontainer").html("<span>liked it!</span>");
                alert(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

What I would like to get is that if the user is anonymous and click on the button he/she is redirected on the default login page. After logged in he is redirected to the current page.
At the moment the async call via Jquery is executed but doesn't trigger the redirection. And if I log in manually it display the string returned by the POST.
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

as i see it you have two options:

(1) when you create the page on the server side you should know if the user is logged in or not.  if he is not logged in, then just render a page in which clicks on that button/link directly redirect to the login page.
if the user is indeed logged in then those buttons/links will post, via ajax, a request just like you showed.

(2) your client is agnostic to rather the user is logged in or not, then when the ajax call is served you check if the user is logged in or not, then you return a response depending on that.  then in the success method of the ajax you check the response, if the user is not logged in you redirect him to the login page, something like

```
document.location.href = path_to_your_login_page;
```